# Resetting a reactjs form after submission

Tags: reactjs, this, reset, react-props, react-forms

I have created a reactjs form that sends data to a django rest api successfully. I want to reset the form after the button has been clicked but it keeps giving me an error saying "this.props.resetState() is not a function. Is there something that can be done to reset all the inputs of the form created after submission?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } from "reactstrap";

import axios from "axios";

import { API_URL } from "../constants";

class ClientForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pk: 0,
            name: "",
            email: "",
            business_name: "",
            country: "",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.client) {
            const {
                pk,
                name,
                email,
                phone,
                business_name,
                country,
            } = this.props.client;
            this.setState(pk, name, document, email, phone);
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    createClient = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post(API_URL, this.state).then(() => {
            this.props.reset();
            this.props.toggle();
        });
    };

    editClient = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.put(API_URL + this.state.pk, this.state).then(() => {
            this.props.reset();
            this.props.toggle();
        });
    };

    defaultIfEmpty = (value) => {
        return value === " " ? " " : value;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.client ? this.editClient : this.createClient}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="name">Name:</Label>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.defaultIfEmpty(this.state.name)}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="email">Email:</Label>
                    <Input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.defaultIfEmpty(this.state.email)}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="phone">Phone Number:</Label>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="phone"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.defaultIfEmpty(this.state.phone)}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="business_name">Business Name:</Label>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="business_name"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.defaultIfEmpty(this.state.business_name)}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="country">Country:</Label>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="country"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.defaultIfEmpty(this.state.country)}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button>Send</Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default ClientForm;
```

Comment: What your "resetState" method does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in your approach, you could reset your component state to an `initialState` value and consequently call `this.setState(this.initialState)` at the end of your form submission handler.

Something like:

```
class ClientForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialState = {
            pk: 0,
            name: "",
            email: "",
            business_name: "",
            country: "",
        };
        this.state = this.initialState;
    }

    (...)

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();        
        this.props.client ? this.editClient() : this.createClient();
        this.setState(this.initialState);
    }

    (...)

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                (...)
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default ClientForm;
```

N.B. Don't forget to remove the `e` parameter and the `e.preventDefault()` call in the `createClient()` and `editClient()` methods.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out to help. I just tried this and it has prevented the react app from sending the data to the database. Also, the inputed values still remain on the form

Comment: It was totally helpful. I omitted setting the this.state to this.initialState. Thanks